Laravel model throws error on point type while creating json
I have a point type in database and I am not able to return json response with this type cause it throws an error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded in JsonResponse.php.
I am pretty sure the problem is in this field cause if I select rows without where point is null everything works fine.
How should I handle this situation. Is there any cast for it?
